# Schedule Optimization in Python for lists of lists [interval scheduling]

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Doing some learning problems in python and I've come across a challenge that I'm having trouble working out.

**Reqs**

- I have a list of lists, where the first and last items are respectively the start and end times of a meeting.
- a 'possible meeting' is one where the start and end times of meeting 1 and 2 can be the same or where 1 < 2, but they can't overlap. So in:
  `[[0,1][1,2][2,3],[2,5]]` there are 3 possible meetings because the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd meetings can all happen sequentially, but the last can't -- or at least if the last can happen the 3rd one can't.
- I need to return the number of possible meetings
- w/o any sort of special knowledge of an appropriate algorithm that would work well here (still learning), my approach has been to sort the lists of lists and compare them to the next one to see if a meeting is possible. All given sets for the problem have at least 1 meeting that can occur (since at least one meeting would necessarily be possible).

Here's what I have so far in python3.4:

```
def answer(meetings):
    index = 0
    nextIndex = index + 1
    possibleMeetings = 1
    impossibleMeetings = 0
    sortedMeetings = sorted(meetings)

    for item in sortedMeetings:
        firstItem = item[1]
        secondItem = sortedMeetings[nextIndex][0]

        if firstItem <= secondItem:
             possibleMeetings +=1
             nextIndex+=1
         elif firstItem > secondItem:
             impossibleMeetings +=1
             nextIndex+=1
        if nextIndex == len(sortedMeetings):
            break
    index +=1
return possibleMeetings, impossibleMeetings
```

Problems:

- I have the feeling that this is a brute-force way to sort things and compare them
- I don't think it will scale well
- There are likely cases that will break it

Any help here would be greatly appreciated! Hoping to expand my conception of what's possible in this sort of problem. Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling

Comment: Should I add 'interval scheduling' to the question title?

Comment: What are you unhappy about with your current code? Are you interested in the maximum number of possible meetings?

Comment: yes :) also, it seems to be a brute-force solution and I suspect it will fail in some cases -- just hoping for some help on approaching it differently

Comment: Also, keep in mind that in the general case, there may be multiple different possible schedules, so unless you want to look at every possible solution, you need some sort of objective function that evaluates each possible schedule and gives it a score of some sort so that you can determine the "best" schedule... Unless all you need is just one possible schedule that isn't necessarily best/worst/anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interval scheduling optimization is a standard problem with a greedy algorithm described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling#Interval_Scheduling_Maximization):

> The following greedy algorithm does find the optimal solution:
>
> 1. Select the interval, x, with the earliest finishing time.
> 2. Remove x, and all intervals intersecting x, from the set of candidate intervals.
> 3. Continue until the set of candidate intervals is empty.

Your current solution only requires O(nlogn) for the sorting, plus O(n) operations for the loop so is a very efficient approach that should scale well.

However, it is not quite correct because:

1. You sort by the starting times, not the finishing times
2. You compare every consecutive pair of meetings

You could fix these problems with the following code:

```
def answer(meetings):
    last_end = -1
    ans = 0
    for end,start in sorted( (end,start) for start,end in meetings ):
        if start >= last_end:
            last_end = end
            ans += 1
    return ans, (len(meetings) - ans)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Given your last two points (1.,2.), what changes would you suggest?